# HTML Vertically Align Text in Header with Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a header with Bootstrap. My `page-header` contains an image and text. I want the text to be vertically centered in the header. It seems like an easy, fix, but I'm running into trouble. I made a custom class called `v-align` where I set the `vertical-alignment: middle;`, but it's not working. Any suggestions?

**Image:** 
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
     <!-- CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div id="form-container">
        <div class="page-header text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="col-xs-4"src="Popcorn.png"  width="100" height="auto" >
                <div class="col-xs-8 v-align">
                    <h2>Sparky's Movie Theater</h2>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Css Class:**

```
.v-align {
    height: 100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you follow this link : https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Add `display:table;` to `.page-header`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my text to be vertically aligned by adding the following to my css code:

**CSS**:

```
#box {
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
}
#spantext {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: normal;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="col-xs-8" id="box">
    <h2 id="spantext">Sparky's Movie Theater</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `padding` and `margin` in `<H2>`

```
h2{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```